# Does Nifi use memory other than allocated Heap Memory?

Tags: apache-nifi

We have given 4GB of memory to heap by mentioning it in bootstrap.conf and all repositories (Content, Provenance, Content & FlowFileRepository) are configured to Disk.  But when NiFi instance runs for a while It starts using 10 GB of memory.

Not able to find where the extra 6 GB of RAM is consumed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be stored in the RAM or JVM memory? It looks like NiFi uses the JVM and RAM to store the memory in some fashion.